# What's the difference between these class in Python?

Tags: python, class, oop, instance, member

I still get confused about the concept of inheritance and OOP.

**Example 1**:

```
import websocket


class Parent1(websocket.WebSocket):

     def __init__(self):
         super().__init__()

     def connect(self, url):
         super().connect(url)

     def send(self, payload):
         super().send(payload)

     def recv(self):
         msg = super().recv()
         return msg
```

**Example 2**:

```
import websocket


class Parent2:

     def __init__(self):
         self.ws = websocket.WebSocket()

     def connect(self, url):
         self.ws.connect(url)

     def send(self, payload):
         self.ws.send(payload)

     def recv(self):
         msg = self.ws.recv()
         return msg
```

I tested all of the above classes as parent classes, but they did the same work.
I can't find good answers that what's the difference between above classes.

Comment: The first _is_ a `websocket.WebSocket` and the second _contains_ a `websocket.WebSocket`.

Comment: (And the first has a bunch of unnecessary code. You can just `pass` the whole body of the class and get the same behaviour since you're just calling the parent class' methods.)

Comment: oh, and none of them are parents.

Comment: Thank you @Chris I couldn't though of that. and, to Madness - This is SE , What does it mean none of them are parents? I don't understand could you explain more specific?

Comment: I didn't make that comment, but in OOP inheritance it would make more sense to call the _base_ class (`websocket.WebSocket` here) the "parent" class. The derived classes (what you've called `Parent1` and `Parent2`) could be called child classes. (I prefer "base" and "derived", but I think most people would understand "parent" and "child" too.)